# Let's get critical: Apr 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Are there technologies that convert algae directly to heat?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/are-there-technologies-that-convert-algae-directly-to-heat)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What is the difference between sustainable living for an individual and a sustainability policy for a company?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2550/what-is-the-difference-between-sustainable-living-for-an-individual-and-a-sustai)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Can you recycle single serve coffee pods like K-Cups?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2501/can-you-recycle-single-serve-coffee-pods-like-k-cups)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What are the steps needed to fix Harbin's smog problem?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2552/what-are-the-steps-needed-to-fix-harbins-smog-problem)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Retrofitting insulation in a 4-storey home. Top down or bottom up?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2584/retrofitting-insulation-in-a-4-storey-home-top-down-or-bottom-up)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I tell biodegradable plastic bags apart from non-biodegradable?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/how-can-i-tell-biodegradable-plastic-bags-apart-from-non-biodegradable)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does it take to stop the use of plastic bags in big grocery stores?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/what-does-it-take-to-stop-the-use-of-plastic-bags-in-big-grocery-stores)

**Net Score: -1** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How safe it is to produce, use, and dispose of PVC?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2579/how-safe-it-is-to-produce-use-and-dispose-of-pvc)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Preserving opened canned food](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2575/preserving-opened-canned-food)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Which one is more sustainable: central A/C or window A/C?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2588/which-one-is-more-sustainable-central-a-c-or-window-a-c)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

Answer (score 2):

Just like last time, we need in principle more participation to benefit from self-evaluation. It is worth noting, though, that the questions received an overall **negative net score**, which isn't necessarily a good sign. I guess there's no need to worry at this stage, but something to be aware of.

It appears that **we need better questions and better answers** (at least by the standard of the 3-4 people, who participated in this self-evaluation round).

Comment: I agree. I also think we should examine the questions that got a negative score and find out in which area they come up short; is it the question, the answers, or a bad ranking on google? Perhaps we can make some improvements.